# Can a single document in a library be excluded from search?

Tags: 2007, search

Is there a way to tell the indexing service NOT TO index a few documents in a library?  Suppose we have a document library with 500 documents and there are 3 that we don't want indexed.  Can those 3 documents not be indexed?  We're using WSS 3.0.

Thank you,
dave

Comment: Could you state why you don't want it searched? Security? Confusion for all users? Some other reason. This could help determine the best way to address this.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Search or Office Search as part of Search Server Express, I'm assuming you're not using Moss. Anyhwo if you're using the Office Search component managed through an SSP using search result removal may work if the url of the document is static.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify if a document library should be indexed (in Document Library Properties).

If you set unique permissions on the document that denies access for the default content access account, I guess the document isnt indexed (its an easy thing to try at least).

Be aware though that item level permissions scale really bad, so it should be kept to a few items

Comment: the crawl account is configures itself with read permissions via Web Application Policy and that will override any permissions defined in the site itself.

Comment: permissions are a good way, it gives the power to the site collection owner, farm/ssp admins aren't bogged down with user requests

Answer (score 2):

Anders' approach would work, and you can also specify a crawl rule to not crawl given documents, or remove the results themselves (both under Search Administration in Central Administration).

Comment: I don't seem to see a Search Administration option.  Is this MOSS specific?  We're using WSS 3.0.

Comment: Good question... it might be.  I only have MOSS handy to check.  Hopefully someone has a copy of WSS and can weigh in :)

Answer (score 0):

Your document library should be grouping documents that are alike. I would create a separate document library for these special documents. It makes managing search crawl, but also permissions/workflow a lot easier. While you can use fine grained permissions per document, do you really want to? Its similar to the benefits of using group based security rather than per user security.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, if you can't create a separate document library, is to try defining a boolean column say "IndexDocument" in your document library whose default value will be "Yes". 
For all those documents which you don't want to be indexed, set the value to "No".

Perform a crawl to get the property as "Crawled Property". 
Define a managed property based on that crawled property. Set it to be used in Scope.

Add a rule based on "Property Query" such as
IndexDocument=No and Select "Behaviour"=Exclude

Update Scopes and you are happy to go.